# Two tables side by side - aligning one table to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display 2 tables side by side on my website (it is actually one table that includes two sub-tables). I used the following template to do it: (found it in http://www.bignosebird.com/docs/h50.shtml)

```
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="500">
  <TR>
   <TD WIDTH=250>
    <TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="250">
     <TR>
      <TD>
       This is in our first table!
      </TD>
     </TR>
    </TABLE>
   </TD>
   <TD WIDTH="250">
    <TABLE BORDER="1">
     <TR>
      <TD WIDTH="250">
       And this is in the second table!
      </TD>
     </TR>
    </TABLE>
   </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

The thing is, I want to align the second table to the right of the screen . I tried:

```
<table border="1" align="right">
```

but it doesn't work. any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Wow, how old is that tutorial?

Comment: A decade at least :) `© 1997-2003` Please tell me you're not building the site layout using tables..

Comment: Back to the future tudududu

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use tables for aligning things.

You could either get rid of the parent table and write it like this:

```
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="250" style="float:left;">
 <TR>
  <TD>
   This is in our first table!
  </TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE BORDER="1" style="float:right;">
 <TR>
  <TD WIDTH="250">
   And this is in the second table!
  </TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Or:
This should be better. Use divs
    
       This is in our first table!

```
<div style="float:right;">
   And this is in the second table!
</div>
```